# Chrome crash during execution of a javascipt in selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome

I want to download the excel file from a [website](https://nrlm.gov.in/mmuMasterReport.do?methodName=getNodalOfficerList) via selenium python. I have written a code as below. During the execution of javascript, My chrome crashed. I am not getting any error messages. Could someone please help me out?

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
chromDriver = ChromeDriverManager().install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromDriver)
driver.get("https://nrlm.gov.in/mmuMasterReport.do?methodName=getNodalOfficerList") 
driver.execute_script("genrateExcel()")
```

Answer (score 0):

In have had a look to your website, replace below statement

```
driver.execute_script("genrateExcel()")
```

with following code and you should be able to download the excel file in your local

```
download_excel= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Download as Excel']")
download_excel.click()
```

Comment: Sorry @Rohit but it doesn't work for me. I am getting an error message "Message: element not interactable: element has zero size  (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.99)".

Comment: try driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download_excel) instead of download_excel.click() and it should work, while there are other alternatives via chrome options that you can get rid of element not interactable while clicking, but javascript will work always.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue,  I was using the code with Jupiter Notebook which is creating a problem somehow. I switched to the command window and it works!